# Extracting values present between the <Div class> tag using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

In the below HTML code,i need to extract the string "PMR/SMR Effectiveness" present in the class "txtDetail". But with my code, it is fetching all the text elements. I've seen multiple examples on stackoverflow for this,but nothing works for me.Please let me know what is wrong in my code.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'html.parser')
for i in soup.find_all(class_ ='default yellowBorder Hclass ' ):
    if soup.find_all('div',attrs={"class" : "txtDetail"}):
        print(i.text)
```

Expected output: PMR/SMR Effectiveness

Actual output: HPPMR/SMR Effectiveness    PMR/SMR Effectiveness   PMR/SMR Effectiveness  Computation Formula   PMR/SMR  is conducted/reviewed as per recommended frequency

HTML code:

```
<ul class="blockList" id="ulexceptionlist"><li class="default yellowBorder Hclass "><div class="blockCont"> <div class="yellowBlock dispBlock expPoints"><div class="iconException">H</div><div class="yellowSection">P</div></div><div class=" nextCont  textCont activeCont " onclick="loadMerticchart(this,&quot;drill1&quot;,&quot; AND m.MetricId=20&quot;,&quot;2&quot;,&quot;PMR/SMR Effectiveness&quot;,&quot;20&quot;,&quot;286&quot;,&quot;0&quot;,&quot;0&quot;)" descopereason=""><div class="txtDetail">PMR/SMR Effectiveness</div></div><div class="infoIcon " id="info1" data-hasqtip="4"></div><div class="col-xs-12 noPadding popupContainer"> <div class="col-md-12 dropdownContent pull-left"> <span class="clearfix"></span> <span class="pull-left content"><h6 class="tooltipTitle"> PMR/SMR Effectiveness </h6> <span class="tooltipCont"> PMR/SMR Effectiveness </span><br><br><h6 class="tooltipTitle"> Computation Formula </h6> <span class="tooltipCont"> PMR/SMR  is conducted/reviewed as per recommended frequency </span></span> </div></div></div></li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you call `.text` on `i` variable which is `li` tag. I've modified your code a bit:

```
for i in soup.find_all(class_ ='default yellowBorder Hclass ' ):
    divs = soup.find_all('div',attrs={"class" : "txtDetail"})
    for d in divs:
        print(d.text)
```